# /dev/root on CentOS7 is almost full?

Tags: centos, hard-disk

i have used Linux for a number of years but usually on Ubuntu and haven't ever had this issue before. The other day all of our web sites on the NGINX VHosts stopped responding and after snooping around it turns out /dev/root had ran out of space. I tried googling but didn't get anything to concrete, i used some of the directory commands i found to output.

```
    [root@server1 ~]# df -h
    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    /dev/root        20G   18G  597M  97% /
    devtmpfs         16G     0   16G   0% /dev
    tmpfs            16G  2.6M   16G   1% /dev/shm
    tmpfs            16G  1.1G   15G   7% /run
    tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    /dev/md3        2.7T   15G  2.6T   1% /home
    tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/0
```

This is in the /root/ directory but it doesn not seem the culprit is in the linked /root i guess.

```
    [root@server1 ~]# du -sh *
    18M     centminlogs
    52K     mysqlreport
    116K    mysqltuner.pl
```

Originally it did actually run out of space entirely, and i managed to make it go down by moving steam, steamcmd, and a few other various repo's and stuff that were living in /root for some reason to /home which worked fine. But now what i listed above is all thats left in /root/ so i have no clue where these hidden files are that are making it run out of space (again).

It has slowly been going down again this entire time and im running out of space again.

Comment: Is /usr/local/share/ considered part of it? There are some game servers running in there. But that is only accountable for 6.1GB, so i am thinking its not. NGINX runs all the site directories in /home/ so that shouldn't be the culprit either i dont think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to work out where the space is being used:

```
du -xak / >/home/sizes
sort -rn /home/sizes >/home/sorted
less /home/sorted
```

The things at the top are the largest directories/files.
Find things in the list that you don't need (which can be deleted) or can relocate to /home, which has lots of space.

Comment: This command showed me that all the stuff in /usr/ was included, and i guess i didn't realize that. I moved more game server files, maps, and storage containers into home and it cleared right up lol. Thank you!